# htaccess redirect including string

Tags: .htaccess

I know how to redirect normal links without strings, but including the string for email addresses has me stuck. Can someone please assist with 301 redirecting a URL to another domain including the URL string? I need to redirect the following:

> www.domain.com/page.php?e=tom-jones@mail.com

to

> www.domain1.com/?e=tom-jones@mail.com

I just need to keep the email address in the string when it's redirected to the new URL

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the htaccess file in your `www.domain.com` document root, you can just add:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/page\.php$ http://www.domaon1.com/
```

The query string will automatically get appended. Or you can use mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^page\.php$ http://www.domaon1.com/ [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Hi Jon, that works perfectly. Thanks so much. :) Bec